# Good Family Tree software?

Tags: genealogy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What genealogy software can you recommend?](https://superuser.com/questions/46050/what-genealogy-software-can-you-recommend)

I am looking for a family tree software, that will allow me to have other members of my family contribute to it (e.g. so maybe web-based).

I know I can google it and there are a million packages out there, but I am looking for recommendations and experiences.

Comment: already asked here: http://superuser.com/questions/46050/what-genealogy-software-can-you-recommend